# LWJGL hangs when loading PNG image using Slick2D TextureLoader

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

On Mac OS X El Capitan, OpenGL version 4.1, my LWJGL 3.0 app hangs when calling the [Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/) function `TextureLoader.getTexture()`

Here's the code I'm attempting to use to load the texture. It is run on the same thread as the main loop, and is called after the window is set up.

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("src/AppIcon.png");
texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", file);
```

The file *does* exist, and the code works fine when I comment out the code for texturing, which is this method

```
public int loadTexture(String filename){
    Texture texture = null;
    try{
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename + ".png");
        //The app freezes here
        texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("png", file);
        //"LOADED" is never printed to the console.
        System.out.println("LOADED");
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     return texture.getTextureID();
}
```

The texture I'm attempting to use is a 1024 x 1024 PNG image,

[image]

I've also tried using a much smaller 16 x 16 pixel image,

[image: 16x16]

but I get the same result.

Both images are physically okay, no errors are logged, and the last thing that is printed in console is from Slick2D, stating

> INFO:Use Java PNG Loader = true

Is this an OS specific bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you run `pngcheck` on your images and check if they are physically okay? They probably are - chances are pretty low *two* images are bad (unless you created them both with the same (bad) software), but still worth checking. Can you add one of these images to your question?

Comment: @Jongware I've added both of the images to the question. They are both physically okay, and I created them using Photoshop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, `Slick2D` is not compatible with GLFW on OS X. Because of this, I had to use the [`stb`](https://github.com/nothings/stb) binding, which is LWJGL 3.0's  [`STBImage`](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-generated/blob/master/java/org/lwjgl/stb/STBImage.java), `org.lwjgl.stb.STBImage`.

Here's the code that I use

```
public int loadTexture(String filename){
    ByteBuffer imageBuffer;
    try{
        imageBuffer = readFile(filename);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    IntBuffer w = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    IntBuffer h = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    IntBuffer comp = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);

    ByteBuffer image = STBImage.stbi_load_from_memory(imageBuffer, w, h, comp, 0);
    if(image == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load image: " + STBImage.stbi_failure_reason());
    }

    this.width = w.get(0);
    this.height = h.get(0);
    this.comp = comp.get(0);

    if(this.comp == 3){
        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, this.width, this.height, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    }
    else{
        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, this.width, this.height, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    }

    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    return GL11.glGenTextures();
}

private ByteBuffer readFile(String resource) throws IOException{
    File file = new File(resource);

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();

    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer((int) fc.size() + 1);

    while(fc.read(buffer) != -1);

    fis.close();
    fc.close();
    buffer.flip();

    return buffer;
}
```

And it works as expected

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the code just has a path to the image, but despite the filetype you put after it (.png) it doesn't know the filetype, try:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename + ".png", PNG);
```

if that doesn't work, I could have messed up the "", so if you get an error again, try this instead (but it likely won't work)

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename + ".png", "PNG");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't work. `FileInputStream` only takes one argument.

Comment: Maybe try ".PNG" instead of ".png"?                                                                          EDIT: oh, I see that it is OS specific... Weird, because I can pass two arguments.... Maybe it's my LWJGL or Slick-Util version :/